# MySQL Error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Okay. I have read through almost everything, except I cannot find the answer to my problem. I don't get what's wrong.. It keeps giving me `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2`

```
CREATE TABLE users (
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't defined any columns in your table.

Comment: Thanks. Whoops. I was trying to test my newly configured PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I have just experienced that in create table query when you mention primary key then you don't get an error. Otherwise you are receiving error. This is a strange experience. well try this

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

You must provide at least one column. And that would be your primary key.

Comment: Defining a `PRIMARY KEY` on a table is optional, and it not the problem. See the other answers regarding missing columns.

Comment: @ The Scrum Meister I totally agree with you but I have just experienced this. When i didnot provide primary key and provided other columns, I also received this problem. But when I provided primarykey i didn't. I am also amazed to see this.

Comment: @awais-qarni Interesting, please file it as a bug if you are able to reproduce it!

Answer (score 0):

Does the second error 1113 answer your query?

```
mysql> create table users();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

mysql> create table users;
ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column
```

Further details can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define a engine?

```
create table users (
    user_id tinyint unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    [.....]
)engine=innodb;
```

Comment: declaring a engine is optional. it will use the db's default engine

Answer (score 0):

Another possible is that you did't　choice database:

```
mysql> create table t(id int);
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+----------------------+
| Level | Code | Message              |
+-------+------+----------------------+
| Error | 1046 | No database selected |
+-------+------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```